# Checking in Windows file explorer if a file or folder is synced with Onedrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, sync, onedrive

When browsing my files and folders, is it possible to see somehow in Windows file explorer if a folder or a file is synced with Onedrive? I know that it can be seen in the Onedrive folder but can I see it at the original place? For example, google drive has such a feature, a small icon indicates it at the corner of the folder icon.

Comment: What do you mean by "...original place"? Only files & folders within the OneDrive folder are synced with OneDrive. That's why OneDrive redirects Desktop, Documents, and Pictures folders when they're selected for " Backup" --- a cause of endless confusion for many.

Comment: My understanding is that if I copy a folder to OneDrive and later on I change the content of that original folder then it is synced with OneDrive. This is what I mean by "original".

Answer (score 1):

Folders which are sync'd have a green tick, those which are being sync'd have a blue arrow. Only folders which are selected for sync will show these icons.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

You can see which folders are selected for sync from the Account tab of the OneDrive settings dialog.

[image]

Is there's no such icon, then the folder hasn't been selected for sync to OneDrive.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no such icons. Can I set it somewhere so that they appear?

Comment: Then go into `choose folders` and add the missing directories.